# IF $A$ is similar to $B$, then $A^{-1}$ is similar to $B^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is similar to $B$ (That is: there is some nonsingular $C$ such that $B = C^{-1} A C $). If $A$ is nonsingular, show that $B$ is also nonsingular and that $A^{-1}$ is similar to $B^{-1}$

#### Attempt:

Suppose $A$ is similar to $B$. So, can find nonsingular $C$ with $B = C^{-1} A C $. IF $A$ is nonsingular, then $B$ must be nonsingular since product of nonsingular matrices is nonsingular. Taking inverses, we have $B^{-1} = (C^{-1} A C )^{-1} = C^{-1} A^{-1} C $ and so $B^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$ are similar.

IS this a correct solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right idea, but $(C^{-1} A C )^{-1} = C^{-1} A^{-1} C$ might need to be justified a little more. You can't just distribute the exponent if that's what you were doing. It's not hard to show that you take the inverse of a product of matrices in reverse order, and that $(C^{-1})^{-1}=C$.

Otherwise, this is fine.